# Reading in json file with encrypted content with U-SQL

Tags: c#, azure-data-lake, u-sql

I'm using [this](https://github.com/Azure/usql/blob/master/Examples/DataFormats/Microsoft.Analytics.Samples.Formats/Json/JsonExtractor.cs) assembly as a json extractor and its all working fine. The json file that is my input is just plain json now. What i'm trying to do is read in a file with encrypted content.

So in the extractor I want to use my C# method that decrypts a string, but I can't figure out how to make this work since i'm not getting a string anywhere. Here's the extract method.

```
public override IEnumerable<IRow> Extract(IUnstructuredReader input, IUpdatableRow output)
    {
        // Json.Net
        using (var reader = new JsonTextReader(new StreamReader(input.BaseStream)))
        {
            // Parse Json
            //  TODO: Json.Net fails with empty input files
            var root = JToken.ReadFrom(reader);

            // Rows
            //  All objects are represented as rows
            foreach (JObject o in SelectChildren(root, this.rowpath))
            {
                // All fields are represented as columns
                this.JObjectToRow(o, output);

                yield return output.AsReadOnly();
            }
        }
    }
```

And here is my decryption method

```
 public static class Decryptor
 {
    private static readonly byte[] _key = Convert.FromBase64String("AAECAwQFBgcICQoLDA0ODw==");
    private static readonly byte[] _iv = Convert.FromBase64String("AAECAwQFBgcICQoLDA0ODw==");

    private static readonly ICryptoTransform _decryptor;

    static Decryptor()
    {
        var myRijndael = new RijndaelManaged { Key = _key, IV = _iv, Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7 };
        _decryptor = myRijndael.CreateDecryptor(myRijndael.Key, myRijndael.IV);
    }

    public static string Decrypt(string input)
    {
        // Create the streams used for decryption. 
        using (MemoryStream msDecrypt = new MemoryStream(Convert.FromBase64String(input)))
        {
            using (CryptoStream csDecrypt = new CryptoStream(msDecrypt, _decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read))
            {
                using (StreamReader srDecrypt = new StreamReader(csDecrypt))
                {
                    return srDecrypt.ReadToEnd();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Is the full file encrypted or fields inside the JSON document? In the first case, you will need to decrypt the baseStream in the extractor. Make sure that you set the extractor property atomicFileProcessing to true.

If only a text property inside the JSON document is encrypted, you have two options:

1. use the extractor to extract the field (remember, they are extracted as key/value pairs in a SqlMap) and then apply a C# user-defined function on the values that need to be decrypted.
2. somewhere deeper inside the JObjectToRow function there will be some code that generates the Map entry. Apply the decryption there.

Comment: Thanks for the input. The full content is decrypted not just the fields. Yeah i'm trying to decrypt the basestream but no succes so far. It doesn't help that I can't really debug it either. Atleast I havent found how. I can turn the basestream to a string (reader.ReadAsString()) and decrypt that but don';t know how to go from there

Comment: I figured out I can create unit tests sample projects so trying that out now so I can see whats going on :)

Comment: Did you update your VS Tooling? You now have the ability to do local debug even of failed vertices.

Answer (score 1):

By changing the extractor to the following I managed to decrypt the contents of my json file.

```
 public override IEnumerable<IRow> Extract(IUnstructuredReader input, IUpdatableRow output)
    {
        // Json.Net
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(input.BaseStream))
        {
            // Parse Json
            //  TODO: Json.Net fails with empty input files
            var text = reader.ReadToEnd();
            var decr = Encryption.Decryptor.Decrypt(text);
            var root = JToken.Parse(decr);

            // Rows
            //  All objects are represented as rows
            foreach (JObject o in SelectChildren(root, this.rowpath))
            {
                // All fields are represented as columns
                this.JObjectToRow(o, output);

                yield return output.AsReadOnly();
            }
        }
    }
```

I changed the JsonTextReader to a StreamReader so I could read the stream as a string. After decrypting it I parsed it into a JToken so the rest of the code still worked as it did before.